# select the old value with select input in laravel 8 blade

Tags: laravel, select, laravel-blade

how to make the old value selected in Laravel 8 blade with select input in edit form.... i tried this way but didn't work:

```
  <select name="category" id="category" class=" @error('category') border-red-500 @enderror rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full">
                        @foreach($categories as $category)
                            <option value="{{$category->id}}" {{ old('category', $category->id) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
```

and this is what inside controller:

```
public function edit(Product $product)
    {
       
        $categories = Category::all();
        return view('dashboard.products.edit', compact('categories', 'product'));
    }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question with more details, like the `select` tag and what is inside your controller? Thank you

Comment: did it...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your product should have a `category_id` so in the loop you need to check it also `$product->category_id === $category->id`.

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    <option value="{{$category->id}}" {{ old('category', $category->id) || $product->category_id === $category->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Based on the code in `edit()` method `old()` wont work. Because there is no old values since your code just return a view.If you need to use that function then you need to redirect with inputs like
 `return redirect()->back()->withInput();`